# ¿ Como poner el buscador de Google a la parte derecha de la barra de navegación?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quiero poner el buscador de google a la parte derecha de la barra de navegación y he probado varias cosas sin éxito.
Tampoco puedo cambiar la apariencia de las letras en color *GOOGLE*
, pues salen con un relieve muy feo. Imagino que se debe a los estilos que tengo de *bootstrad*, pero tampoco se como darle su apariencia natural.
Dejo la muestra del código.
Gracias.

> NOTA: EDITO EL CODIGO.

Edito la pregunta y el código, pues con la ayuda de
@Edgar Gutiérrez he solucionado el problema del buscador de google, pero al mostrar solo la barra de navegación, no se nota que en un dispositivo móvil la barra de navegación taparía, ú ocultaría, parte del contenido de la pagina, Ya que esta se hace mas ancha por la imagen de google. Simplemente se ve lo que digo dando al ejecutar el código que edite, sin dar al botón de PANTALLA COMPLETA, y observar como esta barra tapa contenido. A ver si tiene alguna solución. Gracias

```css
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
 color: #959595;
 }
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: black;
 }
 
.feature {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: greenyellow;
 }
 
.article-intro {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: black;
}
    
.footer-blurb-item {
    padding: 30px;
    }
 
.small-print {
 background-color: #000000;
 padding: 40px 0;

}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
 text-align: center;
 }

.navbar-header .fa-bars{
  color:white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
.navbar-header {
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Fuentes y styles de area de compartir -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway+Dots" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Logo
        </a>
      <!--/ buscador de google-->
      </div>
      <!-- buscador de google-->
      <form class="pull-right" method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
          <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif" border="0" alt="Google" align="absmiddle" style="background: white; ">
        </a>
        <input type=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
        <input Type=hidden name=hl value="es">
        <input type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Búsqueda Google">
      </form>
      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Casa</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Servicios
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
              <li>
                <a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">
                  Desbroces
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Vallados</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Podas y talas</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">Ubicacion</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

  </nav>
      <div class="jumbotron feature">
        <div class="container">

            <h1>Desbroces y limpieza de fincas:</h1>
            <p>Lleva a cabo el desbroce y limpieza mecanizada de todo tipo de terreno, eliminando cualquier especie de hierbas,
                maleza o matorral, combatiendo efizcamente el riesgo de incendios en la época estival.</p>
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">Trabajamos en toda España, si bien la mayoría de nuestros trabajos se centran en las provincias de Ávila, Madrid,
                Segovia, Salamanca, Cáceres y Toledo.</h3>
            <!--<p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Engage Now</a></p>-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Intro -->
        <div class="row page-intro">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Nuestros clientes siempre satisfechos.
                    <small>Vea una muestra de nuestro trabajo</small>
                </h1>
                <p>Nos desplazamos a cualquier parte de España para hacer su proyecto realidad. Vea alguno de los últimos trabajos
                    realizados, y descubrira nuestro compromiso y profesionalidad.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Feature Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/desbroce_img/desbro1.jpg" alt="Desbroces">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">Desbroces</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Desbrozamos y limpiamos toda clase fincas, urbanas, forestales.... Contamos con una amplia gama de maquina
                    para las peores condiciones de trabajo. Desbrozadoras manuales, de cadenas y de martillos </p>
            </article>
            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/vallas_img/vallas9.jpg" alt="Vallados">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_vallas.html">Vallados</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Cerramos su parcela con malla de alambre. Vallamos su finca con postes de madera en gran cantidad de medidas
                    y tratada para el paso del tiempo. Tubo galvanizado, malla de simple torsion, malla ganadera...
                </p>
            </article>

            <article class="col-md-4 article-intro">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/forestal_img/fores14.jpg" alt="Trabajos forestales">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="galeri_forest/gale_fores.html">Trabajos forestales</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Talamos los arboles de su parcela urbana sin crear daños a edificios colindandantes, cuales quiera que sean
                    las circunstancias. Hacemos limpia y entresaque de su bosque, haciendo una selección con el rigor y profesionalidad
                    que dan 30 años de experiencia.</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <footer>
        <div class="footer-blurb">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/podas_img/podando2.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200">
                        <h3>Toda clase de podas</h3>
                        <p>Profesionales de poda en toda clase de arboles: frutales, ornamentales, decorativos..., dandoles
                            a sus arboles el vigor y la energía necesaria para sacarles el mejor rendimiento.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_podas.html">Una muestra</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/caminos_img/camino1.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200">
                        <h3>Caminos de piedra</h3>
                        <p>Arreglamos el viejo acceso a su finca. Creamos para usted un camino digno de la época romana para
                            que se sorprendan las visitas a su chalet. Son muchos los proyectos que nos avalan...</p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_caminos/galeri_caminos.html">Juzgue usted</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 footer-blurb-item">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/caminos_img/pared3.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200">
                        <h3>Muros de piedra</h3>
                        <p>Expertos en la reparación de vancales, muros de piedra, que harán de su finca un lugar rustico y
                            entrañable.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="galeri_muros/galeri_muros.html">Una muestra...</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="social">

            <section>
                <ul id="services">
                    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> Comparta nuestro trabajo con sus amigos.</h2>
                    <li>
                        <div class="facebook">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es&amp;t=Social%20Buttons%20in%20HTML%20only%20using%20Twitter%20Bootstrap%203%20and%20Font%20Awesome%20Icons">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>Facebook</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="twitter">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es&amp;text=Social%20Buttons%20in%20HTML%20only%20using%20Twitter%20Bootstrap%203%20and%20Font%20Awesome%20Icons">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>Twitter</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="youtube">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&amp;url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es">
                                <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>Google+</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="linkedin">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=https://www.desbrocesylimpiezadefincas.es">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>LinkedIn</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="instagram">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/colorlib">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>Instagram</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="github">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/puikinsh/">
                                <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <span>Github</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </section>



        </section>
        <div class="small-print">
            <div class="container">
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> |
                    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> |
                    <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a>
                </p>
                <p>Copyright &copy; miguel-espeso 2017</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- IE10 viewport bug workaround -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Placeholder Images -->
    <script src="js/holder.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola, no entendí el problema, mi monitor es muy grande creo, puedes subir una captura a https://imgur.com/? Y colocar una imagen de cómo es que te sale el error.

Comment: Hola, el error se ve simplemente cuando das a la parte de abajo del código donde pone EJECUTAR, para ver el funcionamiento del código. Pues tienes la opción de PAGINA COMPLETA. Sin das a pagina completa se ve el error que la barra de navegación tapa parte del contenido de la pagina.
De todas te puse una captura en [http://i65.tinypic.com/2e4jdck.jpg] donde se ve la pagina en el ordenador y a la derecha un simulador móvil, Mobile/RWD Tester. Si como ves la barra oculta parte de la web. Gracias, espero a ver dado pistas, ya te que te estas preocupando.

Comment: No se si si me abre explicado, perdona no supe poner la captura donde me digiste. Lo hice pero luego a dar al enlace no se veia. Siento molestarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema en móviles es un problema de tamaños en los anchos de las etiquetas, no son flexibles, sino fijas, habrá un punto donde los elementos tendrán que bajar obligatoriamente.

Te recomiendo para el problema en móviles, cambiar el display del formulario al tipo flex, así:

```
form{
  display: flex;
}
```

De hecho te recomiendo usar este tipo de display, en toda la maquetación como estas aprendiendo puedes hacer el experimento y probar este modelo de caja.

Otra cosa, en el html, el input tiene predefinido un tamaño mínimo de 31, ¿puedes quitarselo? Por que obliga al input a tener un tamaño que puedes especificarlo mejor por css.

```
<!--le quite este atributo size=31 -->
<input type=text name=q maxlength=255 value="">
```

Lo otro que puedes hacer es que el enlace a google desaparezca cuando el dispositivo sea muy pequeño, con los media queries, así:

```
@media (max-width: 620px){
  a[href*="google.com"]{display: none}
  /*La siguiente linea es opcional, la uso por que si desaparece la imagen
   *el formulario se queda "pegado" arriba */
  form{ padding-top: 1.2em; }
}
```

Además, como te comente al principio es imposible evitar que en un punto los elementos bajen porque su tamaño les obliga hacerlo al no ser flexibles (no siempre los elementos lo tienen que ser), por lo que en ese momento, cuando veas que en X tamaño siempre se baja, puedes crear un media querie en ese tamaño y decirle al body que baje los contenidos en X medida para que se ajuste, ejemplo:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){ /*o la medida que consideres*/
  body {padding-top: 5em; } /*o la medida que consideres*/
}
```

Avisame, si se corrige.

Comment: Ideal compañero @Edgar Gutiérrez , elegi la opcion del ocultar el logo de google, cuando se ve menos tosco, o mas bonito que la primera opcion : form{
  display: flex;
}  Muchas gracias, fuistes de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

### Primero, dejame señalarte algunos errores en tu código:

- Tienes dos veces incrustado jquery al final.
- El icono de barra "menu hamburguesa" se compone de 3 span, sugiero que sea uno solo y te apoyes mediante la librería de iconos bootstrap (que de hecho ya tienes linkeada), se inserta de esta forma: **<i>
  class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" </i>** 
  o que lo hagas vía css, creando las otras 3 barras, mediante ::before y ::after.
- La etiqueta **<right>** no existe.
- Las etiquetas **FORM**, **TABLE**, **A** e **INPUT** estan en mayuscula, acostumbrate a escribirlas en minuscula, no es completamente necesario, pero es lo más recomendable.
- No se recomienda desde 2006 maquetar con tablas, es decir usar la etiqueta **TABLE** para acomodar elementos de maquetación como el buscador en tu caso. No hace falta, solo usa CSS para acomodarlos. Sí lo viste en algún ejemplo, deséchalo, es un mal ejemplo.

### Habiendo dicho esto, empecemos por tu problema:

> Quiero poner el buscador de google a la parte derecha de la barra de navegación

Como te dije antes, no hay necesidad de usar las tablas dentro del formulario, pero **basta con que lo incluyas entre el navbar-header y el navbar-collapse** y lo flotes a la derecha. Cómo usas bootstrap, puedes emplear la clase **pull-right** en el form y listo.

> Tampoco puedo cambiar la apariencia de las letras en color GOOGLE , pues salen con un relieve muy feo.

Creo que no tienes muy claras las bases de diseño web. Te aclaro: Las imágenes como tal, no puedes manipularlas con código web, al menos no para borrar cosas como el fondo. En el caso de la imagen que escogiste, es una versión muy vieja de google y esta ya tiene consigo ese relieve blanco que sobresale en fondos negros, esto es porque solo fue pensada para usarse sobre fondos blancos, no oscuros. **puedes incluir por css inline el fondo blanco a la etiqueta img así: style="background: white"** o **colocarle una clase y manipularla con css externo, que es lo más recomendable, así: .logo-google{ background-color: white;}** aunque no queda muy bien.

Si tu intención es que sea el logo de google pero con fondo transparente, te sugiero buscar en el buscador ***"Logo google png"*** te saldrán imágenes del logo de google más actuales y el formato "png" viene con el fondo transparente. También puedes editar el **GIF** en photoshop y quitarle el fondo blanco, pero es la opción más larga.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
 color: #959595;
 }
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: black;
 }
 
.feature {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: greenyellow;
 }
 
.article-intro {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: black;
}
    
.footer-blurb-item {
    padding: 30px;
    }
 
.small-print {
 background-color: #000000;
 padding: 40px 0;

}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
 text-align: center;
 }

.navbar-header .fa-bars{
  color:white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
.navbar-header {
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Fuentes y styles de area de compartir -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway+Dots" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Logo
        </a>
      <!--/ buscador de google-->
      </div>
      <!-- buscador de google-->
      <form class="pull-right" method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
          <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif" border="0" alt="Google" align="absmiddle" style="background: white; ">
        </a>
        <input type=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
        <input Type=hidden name=hl value="es">
        <input type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Búsqueda Google">
      </form>
      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Casa</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Servicios
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
              <li>
                <a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">
                  Desbroces
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Vallados</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Podas y talas</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="#">Ubicacion</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez , la verdad es que busque en google: ¿como añadir buscador a mi web...? Y cogi ese articulo. Ahora he revisado y el articulo es de 2009. Me daba otro error que era al quitar la linea :<img src="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif" border="0" alt="Google" align="absmiddle"> al marcar input para buscar, se iba directamente a google sin dar tiempo a escribir nada. Ya lo revisare con tu amplia y concluyente respuesta, has sido detallista y en tu respuesta y de gran ayuda.Gracias

Comment: Otro problema @Edgar Gutiérrez y es que al verlo en un celular la barra de navegacion, el buscador de Google, oculta la parte de arriba de la pagina, lo que primero se ve. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar ese problema ? He probado a quitar <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif"> y añadi lo siguiente : 
 <input type=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 
placeholder="Busqueda Google">
     <input Type=hidden name=hl value="es">
                <input type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Buscar..."> Añadi placeholder no se si esto estara bien, agradeceria tu opinion

Comment: Actualiza tu post. No borres nada de tu pregunta anterior, solo coloca un separador y coloca el código con las nuevas actualizaciones o crea una nueva pregunta con todos estos detalles y escríbeme por aquí que yo apenas pueda te respondo, porque así solo leyendo, pero sin código completo no entiendo muy bien.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Edgar Gutiérrez , ya edite el codigo, si puedes ayudarme bien, si no optare por quitar el logo de google, vamos , las letras. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```css
    
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
 color: #959595;
 }
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: black;
 }
 
.feature {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: greenyellow;
 }
 
.article-intro {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: black;
}
    
.footer-blurb-item {
    padding: 30px;
    }
 
.small-print {
 background-color: #000000;
 padding: 40px 0;

}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by Quackit.com -->
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Principal</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway+Dots" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                    Logo
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Casa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Servicios
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                            <li>
                                <a href="galeri_desbro/demo.html">Desbroces</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Vallados</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Podas y talas</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="formulario/formpage.html">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">Ubicacion</a>
                    </li>
                   <li>
                    <FORM method=GET action="http://www.google.com/search">
                        <TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">
                                        <IMG SRC="http://www.google.com/logos/Logo_40wht.gif" border="0" ALT="Google" align="absmiddle">
                                    </A>
                                    <INPUT TYPE=text name=q size=31 maxlength=255 value="">
                                    <INPUT TYPE=hidden name=hl value=es>
                                    <INPUT type=submit name=btnG VALUE="Búsqueda Google">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </TABLE>
                    </FORM>
                   </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Search -->
                <!-- <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">buscar</button>
                </form>-->

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            <!-- buscador de google-->
         
            <!--/ buscador de google-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </nav>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Podrías probar a poner el buscador de Google dentro del misma `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` que el resto de componentes de la barra de navegación.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 50px;
 color: #959595;
 }
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 color: black;
 }
 
.feature {
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: greenyellow;
 }
 
.article-intro {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-blurb {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: black;
}
    
.footer-blurb-item {
    padding: 30px;
    }
 
.small-print {
 background-color: #000000;
 padding: 40px 0;

}

.feature,
.page-intro,
.article-intro,
.footer-blurb,
.small-print {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

Respecto a la apariencia de las letras de Google no puedo ayudarte, esto lo vi de pura casualidad, espero sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: Gracias @Mari Cruz Fernandez, esperare si alguien me ayuda con el logo de google y quiero tratar de ponerlo mas a la derecha.